# What is CASCADE CONSTRAINTS equivalent for IBM DB2?

Tags: oracle, db2

I have two environments for my application and in one environment I am using DB2 and Oracle in the other one.
I am using some existing SQL as it's an old application, to drop a table with cascade effect existing SQL is like - DROP TABLE xyz CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

Above SQL is for Oracle and now I want to write similar SQL for DB2, what I can use in place of CASCADE CONSTRAINTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the Db2-platform and Db2-version...

If your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows then there is no syntax equivalent to 'cascade constraints', and if the table being dropped is referenced in an RI constraint either as parent or dependent then the RI constraint gets dropped.

If your Db2-server runs on i-series, then Db2 also has DROP TABLE ... CASCADE (which seems to be functionally equivalent to Oracle cascade-constraints clause), in addition to DROP TABLE ...RESTRICT.

If your Db2-server runs on Z/OS, the there is no syntax equivalent, but as with Db2-LUW, any RI constraints in which the table is parent or dependent get dropped.

Comment: in my case DB2-server runs on AIX. I am considering RI constraints will be dropped as you said for Linux/Unix. Let me know if you have any other thought. I have not tested it yet in my working environment.